# Background color custom uicollectionview

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` which contains custom `UICollectionViewCell`. The collection view has a background image.
I would show the background image, but the collection view (or its cells) has always a white background which prevents my background image to show.
Here is the code:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


     AgendaCollectionCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:agendaCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.delegate = self;
    cell.layer.borderWidth=0.0f;
    cell.layer.backgroundColor              = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    cell.contentView.layer.backgroundColor  = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    cell.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
    cell.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    [cell setCurrentDateAtIndex:([indexPath row]) date:currentMonth events:events];
    return cell;

    }
```

The `AgendaCollectionCell` is very simple: I did a cell by using IB and set all background images to clearColor. Also the collection view use a very basic custom layout.
An excertp of what is shown in the pic:

[image]

The collection view show cells with numbers. Beneath the collection view there is a background which is not shown because of the white color of the cells.
Any hint appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: try with [cell.backgroundView addSubView..

Comment: addSubView...what to add ??

Comment: What image?? I want a transparent background for every cell and just one background for the whole collectionview...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED.
The problem was in the rendering of the custom cell. I used a method (a lost method...) which set the background color of the cell. For non custom cell, the code in my question is correct.

Answer (score 0):

you can also background color for your custom UICollectionView by setting backgroundview for UICollectionView.
    UIView *blueView = [[UIView alloc]init]; 
    blueView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor]; 
    self.collectionView.backgroundView = blueView;